# Can we say that Black hole is a Black body?

Tags: black-holes, thermal-radiation, hawking-radiation

I want to know if a black hole is a black body.I got this doubt while studying photoelectric effects.

I am an 11th grader.I would be glad to have your help.

Comment: Welcome to PSE. We ask our users to show to add a justification to their question. You can always edit your question to add more context and specially try to add what you have found so far.

Answer (score 5):

The [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) theoretically emitted by a black hole has a black body spectrum. So in a sense we could say that a black hole is a black body, although at a really really low temperature (a tiny fraction of a degree above absolute zero). But there is nothing deep about this - it is really just a coincidence of terminology.

Comment: The Hawking radiation does not exist. It has not been observed experimentally and contradicts fundamental laws of nature theoretically (as expressed in the information paradox).

Comment: @safesphere I agree that Hawking radiation has not yet been confirmed experimentally. But can you provide a peer-reviewed source that supports your assertion that it categorically does not exist ?

Comment: @safesphere How does it contradict the fundamental laws of nature?

Comment: I don’t need to. In science, anyone can come up with any idea, but nothing is considered existing until it is experimentally confirmed. Clashing GR and QFT together has to produce non-physical artifacts, because these theories are incompatible. Hence the “Hawking radiation”, “firewall”, and “sub-Planckian” nonsense. Even if the Hawking radiation exists, it would remain undetectable and therefore unphysical for any practical purpose for all foreseeable future. Therefore in practical physical terms a black hole is not a black body, because it does not emit anything that can be actually detected.

Comment: @Mechanic The information paradox states that a black hole evaporation must violate one of the fundamental laws of nature, such as quantum mechanical unitarity or classical general covariance (the equivalence principle). If there is no evaporation, then no laws are broken and no information paradox. In a nutshell, if you fall to a black hole, per your clock it evaporates before you cross the horizon, so you must remain existing. Yet, as observed from outside, everything evaporates, including you. Hence a contradiction of what happened to you called the information paradox.

Comment: @safesphere > *"Therefore in practical physical terms a black hole is not a black body, because it does not emit anything that can be actually detected."* -- Black body does not need to emit some minimal amount of radiation to be a black body. E.g. a black body of zero temperature is a black body, because it absorbs everything coming its way. The fact that it has zero temperature and radiates nothing does not prevent it from being a black body.

Comment: @safesphere > *"In a nutshell, if you fall to a black hole, per your clock it evaporates before you cross the horizon"* -- Why is this true?

Comment: @JánLalinský "*Black body does not need to emit*" - To clarify my objection to the posted answer, a black hole cannot be considered a black body based on the spectrum of the Hawking radiation, because no such a radiation can be detected. Whether or not a black hole can be considered a non-emitting black body is a separate issue, on which I did not comment. As you can see on a Penrose diagram, the horizon effectively is a null infinity and, if it is a black body, then an infinite empty space also is a black body. This doesn't sound right to me, but again, this is beyond the scope of my comment.

Comment: @JánLalinský The main principle of GR is that reality doesn't depend on our choice of coordinates. In remote coordinates, a falling observer doesn't cross the horizon before the black hole evaporates. Therefore the same happens in his own coordinates, except faster. We must wait some trillion trillion years, but for him this happens in real time during the fall due to the magnitude of the time dilation. This classical view however makes little sense, since he gets within the Planck length of the horizon in a second, so what happens in the next trillion years is unclear without quantum gravity.